# Import all Contacts details from thunderbird using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, import, contacts

Here I'm working on one Project that's definition about to import Data or Contacts from Thunderbird suing Codeigniter or PHP. is there any API to work with it. give me some suggestion or example links, I'm stuck over here. help me. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Thunderbird is client side application . to do interact with it you will need some client side app or script while PHP or Codeigniter  are server side script they by them self cannot interact with them directly . you will need some

1. intermediate to export  the contacts from Thunderbird to excel or
   csv format
2. then upload it to server side
3. and then do the import  job